# Java, JFrame, JComponent, Rectangles

Tags: java, jframe, jcomponent

Here are two instances of the exact same code that draws a bunch of rectangles superimposed down a diagonal, except in the second instance there are parentheses around "i^2" for both the x and y values. I believe that the rectangles should begin at (0,0) in both cases, but in the first case they do not begin at the origin. Instead, they begin slightly off from the origin. Why is there a difference when the rectangles are added to the JFrame?

using 
    javax.swing.JComponent
    javax.swing.JFrame
and 
    java.awt.Rectangle

```
for(int i=0;i<600;i++){
            Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(20*i^2, 20*i^2, 50, 100);
            g2.draw(rect1);
}

for(int i=0;i<600;i++){
            Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(20*(i^2), 20*(i^2), 50, 100);
            g2.draw(rect1);
}
```

My code is in two classes. Here is the main class:

```
import javax.swing.JFrame;

public class MainClass {
    public static void main(String[] args){
        JFrame window = new JFrame();
        window.setSize(600,600);
        window.setDefaultCloseOperation(JFrame.EXIT_ON_CLOSE);

        DrawingComponent drawing = new DrawingComponent();
        window.add(drawing);

        window.setVisible(true);
    }
}
```

And here is the code for the DrawingComponent class that makes Rectangles to be added to the JFrame:

```
import javax.swing.JComponent;
import java.awt.Graphics;
import java.awt.Graphics2D;
import java.awt.Rectangle;

public class DrawingComponent extends JComponent{
    public void paintComponent(Graphics g){
        Graphics2D g2 = (Graphics2D) g;

        for(int i=0;i<600;i++){
            Rectangle rect1 = new Rectangle(20*i^2, 20*i^2, 50, 100);
            g2.draw(rect1);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: How are you performing the painting? Consider providing a runnable example

Answer (score 0):

**The expression `20*i^2` is not the same as `20*(i^2)`.**

Bitwise XOR operator `^` has lower precedence than multiplication `*` and so the two expressions will produce different results.